# applicationhost history with shares configs

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008, iis, iis-7.5

We currently have an IIS setup that uses one applicationhost.config for two servers, this works fine and changes are shared without a problem. The only problem we have is that the #:\inetpub\history\ only backups the local configs which are a 100 years old.

Is there a way to change the source of IIS's applicationhost history method? Like something with appcmd, a deeper specify?

Comment: This blog post suggests it can't be done; "appcmd add backup" only backs up local configuration. You need to setup a manual backup for the shared config outside of IIS.
http://mvolo.com/backing-up-and-restoring-iis-70-shared-configuration/

Comment: Thank you Steve365. Guess we will have to configure a backup method without appcmd. Marked as answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It cant be done the way I wanted it, see comment of Steve365:

> This blog post suggests it can't be done; "appcmd add backup" only backs up local configuration. You need to setup a manual backup for the shared config outside of IIS. mvolo.com/backing-up-and-restoring-iis-70-shared-configuration